# Justifying that the derivative doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits

Is the right way of justifying that the derivative of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ at $x=0$ calculting, by th definition,
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$$
via left and right havd limits? I mean, it is necessary (or correct) to use it in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are "lateral limits"? $\;$

Comment: I meant left and right hand limits.

Comment: @Giiovanna Your idea is correct.